# buildroot new fs can't install grub2

Tags: buildroot

I'm traing to use buildroot and compile new embedded system for testing.
Everything looks ok I use last kernel 4.9.16 and buildroot is from 02.2017. After compiling I can't install grub2 there's now grub software on new root file system and second there's now bash in /bin and anywhere? There's only ash shell.
It's weird because the same procedure I made on mint 17 couple days ago and it works like a charm. I changed disk in my laptop and now I'm using fresh manjaro. I don't think this could be a problem because when I compile new system I can't chose bash in menu but I chose grub2 as bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `bash`: Buildroot by default only installs Busybox, which provides a more minimalistic shell called `ash`, which is sufficient for most purposes. If you really need `bash`, you can also get it by enabling it in the Buildroot menuconfig.

Regarding `grub2`, please have a look at the help text of the Grub2 option in Buildroot, it explains how to install it.